# SQL Get Data for the last 24 Months and Order Months accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am working with the SQL below, but the results that comes out does not give me January data for 2017 result.

The results I get are Feb - Dec, rather than Feb - Jan.

```
SELECT CSE.[CaseID],
       YEAR(CSE.[StartDate]) AS [YEAR],
       CSE.[StartDate],
       CSE.[EndDate],
       (
           SELECT dbo.[MI_GetTotalWorkingDays](CSE.[StartDate], CSE.[EndDate])
       ) AS [Days]

INTO #TMP
FROM dbo.[Case] CSE
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee EMP
        ON CSE.EmployeeID = EMP.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Company CMP
        ON CMP.CompanyID = EMP.CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.UnitNameWithParentsVM) AS DIV
        ON DIV.UnitId = EMP.UnitID
WHERE Month(CSE.[StartDate]) > month(DATEADD(MONTH, -37 , GETDATE()))
AND CMP.CompanyID = @CompanyId;

SELECT 
       YEAR(StartDate) AS [Year],
       MONTH(StartDate) AS [Month Number],
       DATENAME(MM, StartDate) AS [Month Name],
       SUM([Days]) AS [Days Lost]
INTO #PREVIOUS_YEAR
FROM #TMP
WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM, StartDate),
         YEAR(StartDate),
         MONTH(StartDate);

SELECT 
       YEAR(StartDate) AS [Year],
       MONTH(StartDate) AS [Month Number],
       DATENAME(MM, StartDate) AS [Month Name],
       SUM([Days]) AS [Days Lost]
INTO #CURRENT_YEAR
FROM #TMP
WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM, StartDate),
         YEAR(StartDate),
         MONTH(StartDate);

SELECT P.[Month Name],
       COALESCE(P.[Days Lost], 0) AS [Previous Year Days Lost],
       COALESCE(C.[Days Lost], 0) AS [Current Year Days Lost]
FROM #PREVIOUS_YEAR P
    LEFT JOIN #CURRENT_YEAR C
        ON P.[Month Number] = C.[Month Number]
ORDER BY 
p.[Year],
P.[Month Number];
```

A sample of the data is below,

```
YEAR    |StartDate  |EndDate    |Days   
2017    |05/01/2017 |NULL       |283   
2017    |11/01/2017 |NULL       |279
2017    |23/01/2017 |NULL       |271    
2017    |19/01/2017 |NULL       |273    
2017    |01/02/2017 |NULL       |264    
2017    |02/02/2017 |NULL       |263    
2017    |20/02/2017 |NULL       |251    
2017    |22/02/2017 |NULL       |249    
2017    |27/02/2017 |NULL       |246    
2017    |22/03/2017 |NULL       |229
2017    |23/03/2017 |NULL       |228
```

If I go back 37 months I get 2016 data, but that seems a little odd to me. But the question is why is the Jan 2017 Data not being shown

This is the output from the query

```
February    |475    |1515
March       |814    |1137
April       |286    |886
May         |643    |574
June        |2112   |1486
July        |572    |1119
August      |987    |312
September   |2054   |1134
October     |1587   |1645
November    |2129   |0
December    |1672   |0
```

The SQL Fiddle can be found here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9e389

Ive now managed to get a working fiddle as per the above link.

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: Please provide sample data in a consumable format (table variable or DDL + Insert or whatever). Furthermore, what IS the earliest month in your table? Because basically, Jan - Dec doesn't sound wrong...

Comment: @Tyron78 I am looking for last 24 months from date of query, so I would expect Feb - Jan results. I will edit the question to give some sample data

Comment: @Tyron78 does my edit help you better?

Comment: @CodeWarrior You've been here long enough to know that sample data is best served as DDL+DML. You don't really expect us to debug your sql code if we can't run it, right?

Comment: @CodeWarrior yes, a little. And another question: you say you go back 37 Month, but your first query states `month(DATEADD(MONTH, 37  , GETDATE()))` which would be 37 month in the future... is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: @Tyron78 not thats a typo on my part, should be negative 37

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I dont typically ask SQL questions so I dont typically have to provide data. what do you mean by DDL + DML

Comment: DDL - Data definition language. Create table statement in this case. DML - Data manipulation language - Insert into statements in this case.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you for the clarification.  I will get this in shortly

Comment: @ZoharPeled the fiddle wouldnt allow me to put in a larger dataset so this is the best I can give right now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16d67

Comment: `Month(CSE.[StartDate]) > month(DATEADD(MONTH, -37 , GETDATE()))` seems weird, since `Month()` never returns anything above 12.

Comment: @SergeFonville ive been clutching at straws to look at getting the data. This was down to thinking that it wasnt getting the right values back for 24 months, and the 37 in my actual sproc is a variable.  In this SQL here thats just fat fingers from the default value from when i originally posted this